# Succesful mongo shell login leads to Unauthorized errors in log

Tags: mongodb

When logging in with mongo shell, two unauthorized error messages are logged:

```
Unauthorized: not authorized on admin to execute command { getLog: "startupWarnings", ...
Unauthorized: not authorized on admin to execute command { replSetGetStatus: 1.0, forShell: 1.0 ...
```

Similarly, when accessing mongo with Compass GUI, 5 unauthorized messages are logged:

```
Unauthorized: not authorized on admin to execute command { hostInfo: 1, ...
Unauthorized: not authorized on admin to execute command { getCmdLineOpts: 1, ...
Unauthorized: not authorized on config to execute command { dbStats: 1, ...
Unauthorized: not authorized on local to execute command { dbStats: 1, ...
Unauthorized: not authorized on admin to execute command { getCmdLineOpts: 1, ...
```

Note that in both cases, the user does not notice something is going wrong; both clients are fully functional.

There messages are really polluting the log files, making it hard to set alerts on really important unauthenticated messages (for example a backup script not being able to login; i would definitely like to be able to distinguish such messages from this noise). Is there a way to suppress these messages, for example, can i configure a log level causing these messages to go without losing serious messages about, for example, users not being able to authenticate?

Comment: Maybe simply grant execution of these commands to the user

Answer (score 0):

I believe the shell errors come from the default prompt where it tries to show status of the replica. You can overwrite it with custom one https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-mongo-shell/

Compass is a bit more complex and way less customisable. I would recommend to solve the problem from the other end - upgrade your log monitoring tool to be able to ignore irrelevant errors. It's less ideal but much more practical.

Answer (score 0):

The user that you are using with mongo shell appears to be restricted. Let's say your system is configured to only allow certain actions to be performed by specific users.

At the same time, you expect your users to use the mongo shell which permits performing all kinds of operations, including administrative ones.

You will inevitably have many authorization errors from users mistyping commands, trying to peek into databases they don't have access to (intentionally or not), trying to inspect state they are not allowed to inspect, etc.

In a system like this, if you specifically want to debug failed *authentications*, filter those out of the logs and act on them. The json logs introduced with 4.4 server should make this much easier.

Keep in mind that by saying

> without losing serious messages about, for example, users not being able to authenticate?

... you are assigning high importance to a person *mistyping their password* which happens all the time.